# How to preserve leading tabs in AWK when stripping empty lines?

Tags: awk

**EDIT (Problem solved, question misframed, see below)**

I have a file with sample scripts like so:

```
if (test == 1) {


    if (test2 == 2) {

        doSomething();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use AWK to strip away the blank lines via:

```
awk 'NF' filename1 > filename2
```

This results in all leading tabs being squished like so:

```
if (test == 1) {
 if (test2 == 2) {
  doSomething();
 }
}
```

Instead I'd like AWK to preserve the original leading tabs (whilst stripping the blank lines) like so:

```
if (test == 1) {
    if (test2 == 2) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Anyone?

**EDIT (PROBLEM SOLVED)**

I just tested it again, and it seems that the original

```
awk 'NF' filename1 > filename2
```

works. The result filename2 failed because filename1 was an interim file output from g++ which was the program that did the squishing.

Sorry for the confusion and mistake, and thanks to those who responded.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
awk '!/^$/'
```

**Test**

```
$ awk '!/^$/' inputFile
if (test == 1) {
    if (test2 == 2) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution not involving awk would be to use grep like

```
grep . filename
```

selects everything except newline.

**TEST:**

```
$grep . temp
if (test == 1) {
        if (test2 == 2) {
                    doSomething();
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do it in place with:

```
perl -i -lne 'print if(/./)' file
```

if there is atleast one character in the line it willbe printed. else it will simply delte the line. -i makes sure it happens in place without a temporary file

Comment: Please explain what this does.

Comment: This will print lines with only spaces though.